# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts' Why is it happening?

Tags: python, pandas

**I have a `pandas.DataFrame`, `df` called 'books' with column `'title'`.**

```
books = pd.DataFrame([['History of Canada', 'John'], 
                  ['World History', 'Culpher'],
                 ['American Politics', 'Millerson']
                 ], columns=['title','author'])
```

**When I run, it shows its series:**

```py
   titles = books['title']
   type(titles)
```

*pandas.core.series.Series*

**But when I add `value_counts()` after `regex` it gives the error.**

```
   titles.str.extract(r'(History)', flags=re.I).value_counts()
```

*AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'*

**If you run the above without value_counts() it runs with the following result:**

```
    0
0   History
1   History
2   NaN
```

- **Why is the error occurring?**
- **Why does it change from `Series` to `DataFrame`?**

Comment: Please share some dummy data and explain your problem with that data. Try and make your problem statement as reproducible as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Why is the error occurring?
- Why does it change from Series to DataFrame?

Answer: As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), extract returns DataFrame by default since expand = True by default.

The correct way is to set `expand = False` if you want Series as output.

> If expand=False and pat has only one capture group, then return a Series (if subject is a Series) or Index (if subject is an Index).

```
titles.str.extract(r'(History)', flags=re.I, expand=False).value_counts()

History    2
Name: title, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Was pulling my hair for a while now :)
Do you know why it changes from series to df?

Answer (score 0):

as documentation here [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html),there is a parameter call `expand`.

If expand is True, return DataFrame with one column per capture group. If False, return a Series/Index.default value is True.Thats why it returns a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a single line using **`pandas.Series.str.contains()`**.

```py
books.title.str.contains('History').sum()
```

**Output**:

```
2
```

Comment: @Yash What you are trying to achieve can be done even simply as I showed above. Is there any particular reason why you are trying to use specifically `str.extract`?

Comment: I am still learning but from what i understand you can create frequency table by using extract. Eg: make the last book title: 'American Political history'.

If you run books.title.str.contains('History', flags=re.I).sum()
Output: 3

But if you run: 
titles.str.extract(r'(History)', flags=re.I, expand=False).value_counts()
Output:
history 1,
History 2